# Change Height and Width using TextInput in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In React Native I want to take input of height and width in TextInput and when I will click a button then the height and width of this page will change with respect to my input. The initial value of height and width is 100% . If anyone has an answer for this please help me.
My React Native version is 0.59.5

Interface of my screen:

[image: Interface of my screen]

My Current Code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Alert,
    StatusBar,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Picker,
    ScrollView,
    TextInput,
    SafeAreaView,
    ImageBackground,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Button,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

export var DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
export var DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
//import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { Colors } from '../../GloblaScripts/Colors';
import { IndexStyles } from '../../GloblaScripts/Styles';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { ToolBarStyles } from '../../GloblaScripts/Styles';
import Welcome from './Welcome';
import {
    CUSTOM_DEVICE_HIGHT,
    CUSTOM_DEVICE_WIDTH,
} from '../../../index.android';
const next = (
    <Icon name='phonelink-setup' size={30} color={Colors.white}></Icon>
);
const skip = <Icon name='skip-next' size={30} color={Colors.white}></Icon>;

//const image = require('../Images/office.png');
export default class Index extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height: CUSTOM_DEVICE_HIGHT,
            width: CUSTOM_DEVICE_WIDTH,
        };
    }
    // componentDidMount() {
    //  setInterval(() => {
    //      this.setState({
    //          height: '50%',
    //          width: '50%',
    //      });
    //  }, 5000);
    // }
    setCustomHeight = () => {
        this.setState({
            height: this.state.height,
        });
    };
    setCustomWidth = () => {
        this.setState({
            width: this.state.width,
        });
    };
    onNext = () => {
        DEVICE_HEIGHT = this.state.height.toString();
        DEVICE_WIDTH = this.state.width.toString();
        Actions.push('Welcome', { height: DEVICE_HEIGHT, width: DEVICE_WIDTH });
        //Alert.alert(DEVICE_HEIGHT);
    };

    onSkip = () => {
        Actions.push('Welcome', { height: '100%', width: '100%' });
        //Alert.alert(DEVICE_HEIGHT);
    };

    render() {
        //const height = this.state.height;
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: this.state.height,
                    width: this.state.width,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.accentColor,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                }}
            >
                <View style={IndexStyles.top}></View>
                <View style={IndexStyles.middle}>
                    <Text style={IndexStyles.textContainer}>Are you read to go!!!!!</Text>
                    <View style={IndexStyles.formArea}>
                        <View
                            style={{
                                padding: 20,
                                alignContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text
                                style={{
                                    alignContent: 'center',
                                    fontWeight: '500',
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                }}
                            >
                                Give Height and Width
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <View style={IndexStyles.formItems}>
                                <TextInput
                                    placeholder='Height'
                                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                                    onChangeText={(height) => this.setState({ height })}
                                    style={IndexStyles.Input}
                                    //value={this.state.height}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={IndexStyles.formItems}>
                                <TextInput
                                    placeholder='Width'
                                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                                    //onChangeText={(width) => this.setState({ width })}
                                    style={IndexStyles.Input}
                                />
                            </View>

                            <View style={IndexStyles.Button}>
                                <TouchableHighlight
                                    style={IndexStyles.mainBtn}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                        this.onNext(this.state.height, this.state.width)
                                    }
                                >
                                    <Text>{next}</Text>
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                                <TouchableHighlight
                                    style={IndexStyles.mainBtn}
                                    onPress={() => this.onSkip()}
                                >
                                    <Text>{skip}</Text>
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```